# OAuth2: Publishing to multiple Social Websites

Tags: node.js, facebook, authentication, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I need to publish a text to multiple social-media websites and I will choose which websites it will be published (select buttons).

Lets assume I have chosen LinkedIn and Facebook.

Is there anyway I can publish this without prompting the credential information to the user (supposing I already have all the credentials info in the back-end), I mean directly send the credentials to OAuth2?

I'm developing this using Node.js.

Comment: No it is not possible to Facebook. Both there is no API for it and secondly Facebook Platform Policy specifically say you can not handle username and passwords

Comment: Ooh, that's right. I think I can't handle it directly...at least not with FB and IN. Thanks for your clarification, by the way.